# React Context + Firebase Auth not populating onAuthStateChanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, react-context

I've been struggling with this for a while. My context provider below isn't triggering any onAuthStateChanged changes - i.e. it's not populating the user, even though they're logged in.

`AuthProvider.js`

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { firebaseAuth } from '../firebase/firebase';

export const AuthContext = createContext({ loggedIn: false });

const AuthProvider = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ loggedIn: false, email: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log(user); // Fires once "null"
      console.log(firebaseAuth.currentUser); // Fires once "null"
      if (user) {
        console.log('logged in');
        setUser({ loggedIn: true, email: user.email });
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in'); // Fires once
        setUser({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

`firebase/firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firebase-firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREABSE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export default firebaseApp;
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthProvider from './providers/AuthProvider';
import Routes from './components/Routes';
import './App.scss';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As noted above, I get console output once from AuthProvider.js - null, null and "not logged in".

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why it's not populating my user when logged in?
Thanks!

Comment: The code seems OK since your `onAuthStateChanged` callback fires. Are you sure the user is logged in, and if so, how do you know? How does your code for logging the user in look?

Comment: I'm using firebaseui for the login. I don't see any error messages from the login process. Is there a way to test if it's working?

Comment: In my network tab on the console it does make a call to getAccountInfo, which returns populated with my user data, so it seems I'm definitely logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in my UI Config. I had `signInSuccessUrl: '/'`. Once I removed that, it worked.